# HQL - How to Copy/Move data in few partitions from one table to another

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive

I have a Table (main_table) which is partitioned and stores history of records with a flag to indicate if the record is deleted or not. I have another table9del_table), which has same schema as main_table, but stores only deleted records for a day (delete_falg='Y').

As a process I need to move records available in del_table to main_table on daily basis. I am trying to write a LOAD DATA INPATH command, which could move data available in respective partitions of del_table to corresponding partitions of main_table but none of my tries seems to work. Please let me know if it is possible to achieve it by using LOAD DATA INPATH command, withoud specifying individual partitions?

I am trying below steps but it is failing in 2nd step:
set nonstrict hive property:

LOAD DATA INPATH '...../del_table/' into table main_table partition(partition_col_name)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the Loan data inpath?

If not you could do the following https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert

This would regenerate the whole table daily though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this property first:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

then run your command:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '...../del_table/' into table main_table partition(partition_col_name)
```

For more info you can refer to this link: [Partition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert)

Comment: I get following error when I run the above LOAD INPATH command: Failed: Semanticexception Line.. Invalid path ''...../del_table/'': source contains directory: ....../del_table/partitions_col_name=1

Comment: Please tell me two things:
1.) Is your table external/internal ?
2.) Your data files are in local/HDFS ?

Comment: 1.) Is your table external/internal ? - Internal    2.) Your data files are in local/HDFS ? - HDFS.       Just to explain things better I will give simple pseudo code: Let's say I have a table Tab1 with partition on Col1 and it has data for 10 partitions. To simulate my scenario, let's create 2 more tables Tab2 and Tab3. Load tab2 with data in partitions 1 and 2 from Tab1 (using Load data inpath command for specific partitions). Similarly load tab3 with data in partitions 3, 4 and 5 from Tab1. I want to use load data inpath command to move all the data available in Tab2 to Tab3.